# How to not save changes in file (And in temp buffer too!)?

Tags: emacs

Must be stupid question but for some time using Emacs I have no idea how can I to not apply my changes...

When I quit C x C c it tells me :

- Type SPC or `y' to save the current buffer;
- DEL or `n' to skip the current buffer;
- RET or `q' to give up on the save (skip all remaining buffers);
- C-g to quit (cancel the whole command);
- ! to save all remaining buffers;
- C-r to view this buffer;
- d to view changes in this buffer;
- or . (period) to save the current buffer and exit.

So here is some chances to not save changes : n or q but there is always saving buffer of current stage :(

I mean for example when I break some file by adding random text there and I don't want to save changes I want to start edit next time not-saved (not broken) file but Emacs is always opening saved buffer :( How to solve it?

Comment: If you press n then it won't save it.

Comment: yes but read, after I will emacs this file again it will open edited temp buffer.

Comment: It shouldn't do it by default unless you installed some package which does it. Out of the box emacs throws away your changes if you press n.

Comment: here is .emacs: https://github.com/nCdy/Ruto/blob/master/.emacs

Comment: Run `emacs -Q` to verify what the default behaviour is without evaluating any config files. Running `emacs -q` will load site-wide files, but not your personal config. That should let you narrow it down to either the site config, or your own config, and then you'll know where to start looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your phrasing of the question is very confusing.  I think you want to add
revert to the list of options offered?  This code adds <kbd>,</kbd> for revert
and <kbd>%</kbd> to mark buffer as not modified:

```
(when (boundp 'save-some-buffers-action-alist)
  (setq save-some-buffers-action-alist
        (cons
         (list
          ?%
          #'(lambda (buf)
              (with-current-buffer buf
                (set-buffer-modified-p nil))
              nil)
          "mark buffer unmodified.")
         (cons
          (list
           ?, 
           #'(lambda (buf)
               (with-current-buffer buf
                 (revert-buffer t))
               nil)
           "revert buffer.")
          save-some-buffers-action-alist))))
```